# Access denied finding property "ro.vendor.df.effect.conflict"

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer, audio-recording

Hi i am doing audio recording its throwing me an error.

i am not able to figure it out can some one help me.

```
2021-01-24 19:21:53.708 4661-4661/com.koteswara.mediarecordersample E/libc: Access denied finding property "ro.vendor.df.effect.conflict"
    2021-01-24 19:21:53.716 4661-4703/com.koteswara.mediarecordersample E/Perf: Fail to get file list com.koteswara.mediarecordersample
    2021-01-24 19:21:53.716 4661-4703/com.koteswara.mediarecordersample E/Perf: getFolderSize() : Exception_1 = java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to get length of null array
    2021-01-24 19:21:53.716 4661-4703/com.koteswara.mediarecordersample E/Perf: Fail to get file list com.koteswara.mediarecordersample
    2021-01-24 19:21:53.716 4661-4703/com.koteswara.mediarecordersample E/Perf: getFolderSize() : Exception_1 = java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to get length of null array
```

Comment: I'm getting this error and am not doing audio recording.

Comment: @AlguemMeugla Hey man, how did you manage to fix it, because I am not doing audio recording also, and facing same issue as yourself?

Comment: @Milos sorry I don't even remember what was this about.

Comment: @AlguemMeugla don't worry bro, I don't even remember how did i fix it, I think it just gone by itself..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am posting my answer it may help others as well. I solved it by changing my **file directory path** as

```
getExternalFilesDir("/").getAbsolutePath(), "filenme.wav"
```

instead of :

```
Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "filename.wav"
```

Answer (score 0):

I was also getting a similar error, for me, it was resolved by adding `android.enableJetifier=true` to `gradle.properties`.